# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Get request not going thru

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an issue with the following piece of code that is working properly when i run this on my local machine but fails returning 404 when published on a server. 
At first I thought it was due to it not being able to get the file(path problem or smth) but it appears to be that when i call this method like

```
http://.../api/Handler/GetUserPhoto?AgentID=XXX
```

its not even hitting the breakpoint at the beginning of the method. So I assume Get request is not routed properly. But why this only happens on server and where should i look for the source of the problem?

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetUserPhoto(int AgentID)
    {
        try
        {
            UserPhotoResponseContract response = _Client.GetUserPhotoAsync(AgentID).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content;

            //if picture not found in db then return predefined default picture
            if (response.Image.Length < 10) {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "/wwwroot/images", "blank_agent_200.png");

                Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider provider = new Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/wwwroot/images/");
                Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo("blank_agent_200.png");
                var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();

                return base.File(readStream, "image/png", filePath);
            }

            return base.File(response.Image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png), "image/png");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

Controller attributes:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HandlerController : Controller
```

Solution being published to the IIS server via webdeploy and running Kestrel on IIS.

i set this in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\v10.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
```

but i do not see it creating any log output.

changed method to:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult GetUserPhoto(int AgentID)
{
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

And it is doing the same thing, 200 on local but 404 on server.

**EDIT 2**

IIS log:

```
2019-08-15 12:28:48 10.54.0.12 GET /api/Handler/GetUserPhoto AgentID=781 80 - 10.53.0.157 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/76.0.3809.100+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 15
2019-08-15 12:28:49 10.54.0.12 GET /api/Handler/GetUserPhoto AgentID=781 80 - 10.53.0.157 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/76.0.3809.100+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 15
2019-08-15 12:29:39 10.54.0.12 GET /api/Handler/GetUserPhoto AgentID=781 80 - 10.53.0.157 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/76.0.3809.100+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 15
2019-08-15 12:29:39 10.54.0.12 GET /api/Handler/GetUserPhoto AgentID=781 80 - 10.53.0.157 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/76.0.3809.100+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 0
2019-08-15 12:29:40 10.54.0.12 GET /api/Handler/GetUserPhoto AgentID=781 80 - 10.53.0.157 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/76.0.3809.100+Safari/537.36 - 404 0 2 31
```

**EDIT 3**

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //Middleware for exception filtering
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));

    app.Use(next =>
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/test"))
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hit!");
            }
            else
            {
                await next(context);
            }
        };
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    //Anti-forgery configuration
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        //}

        return next(context);
    });

    //Middleware to work with headers
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(HeadersMiddleware));

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @Eyal it gives me the same generc 404 error: "The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server...."

Comment: seems like we're maybe missing a bit of info, do you have any [Route] attributes on the controller? also how are you publishing it to a server? is it running kestrel? iis? any proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by 404 error with `"The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server...." `? Have you enabled custom error handling? Try to comment out the content in `GetUserPhoto(int AgentID)` and return `Ok("Success")` directly to check whether the route is correctly. Does this issue happen to this specific method or all action? Try to enable [ASP.NET Core Module stdout log (IIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis) and share us the detail result.

Comment: @TaoZhou I included answers to all the questions in my edits

Comment: @TonyRanieri no proxy, I added info to the edited question

Comment: @AnKing, Could you please try using "HandlerController" instead of "Handler"?
Like this:
"http://.../api/HandlerController/GetUserPhoto?AgentID=XXX"

Comment: @JustShadow same thing - 404. I have a bunch of other methods like [HttpPost("[action]")] that respond on "http://.../api/Handler/" without any issues. So i'm wondering if there can be some sort of IIS filter for get requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to comment, so I'll post a way to debug your problem and to narrow down where it might be coming from - the server, or from ASP.NET Core's routing:

Let's check if your server actually receives any client requests, by adding a simple middleware for the job.

In the Configure method:

```
app.Use(next =>
        {
            return async context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/test"))
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hit!");
                }
                else
                {
                    await next(context);
                }
            };
        });
```

Make sure you add the above code before `app.UseMvc`, just in case.
Now when you start your web server with the following code added, try going to `<yourserver's ip>:<port>/test` with your favorite web browser.

If you see the message **"Hit!"** on the page, then your server is working properly and accepting requests. If you don't see anything, then something else is going on, and the source of the problem is almost always the server's configuration, unless you've supplied incorrect ASP.NET Core configuration for it.

It's worth trying to explicitly state the route by using the Route attribute instead of the built-in template for `HttpGet` if all else fails.

```
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserPhoto() // removed input here and also changed 
{                                // the name slightly just to make it easier to test
   return Ok("Success");
}
```

Comment: It does return "Hit!" on server!

Comment: @AnKing Hmm, I've no idea what might be causing this as of now... :/ Make sure you remove the middleware. The version of it you're now using doesn't pass control flow to the other middlewares in the request pipeline, effectively rendering your mvc useless. I've updated my post with a proper version of it.

Could you post your Startup.cs?

Comment: it did work on a server when i used "[Route("[action]")][HttpGet]..." I added startup.cs configure method to my original question, maybe that can shine some light

Comment: It appears the source of the problem was that SPA was working out of relative path on server "http://address/webapp/..." but on locan it was working in absolute. this was the issue all the time. I had to replace ui logic to point to the proper place based in environment. Thanks for all the troubleshooting efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You might try `[HttpGet("[controller]/[action]")]]`.